# Does a disk image include applications and can it be restored as a system image?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, disk-image

I am planning to install a Linux installation on my Windows 10 computer and to have it run side-by-side along Windows.

In case something goes wrong I want to create a disk image, as far as I know when resorting this disk image all apps like Microsoft Excel will be restored as well, am I correct?

Also when restoring a disk image, I found from a search this can be restored using the advanced startup tools:

[image]

In the above menu it says:

> Recover Windows using a specific **system image file** (emphasis mine)

Can a disk image be restored as a system image? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: the type of image and tools used to create it are important. A true disk image is a bit-by-bit duplicate of a disks physical binary layout, and will contain everything on that disk. These images are not always the most useful type for all purposes though, so some companies take specialized images like those without drivers (so its portable across hardware) or those without windows licensing information, or a myriad of other proprietary customizations. definitely look into the (high-level) details of the particular imaging type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A disk image is a snapshot of the complete disk, containing *all* information, including some of which you might not be aware:

- Boot partition: how the computer first starts
- Active operating system partitions: usually, at east one partition for each OS, such as Windows and NTFS
- Hidden Windows Restore partition: contains information to return to original state.

[image: Example Main HDD Partitioning]

Above is an example of all that would be saved in a disk image of a particular PC.

An image is an excellent safety-net, allowing you to restore everything, or to open the image in a browser and restore only what is needed.

[A Windows System Image](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5495-create-system-image-windows-10-a.html) "is an exact copy of all system disks which can be used to restore your PC to the state it was in at the time the image was made. By default, a system image only includes the drives that Windows requires to run, including Windows 10 itself, your system settings, programs, and files." This would not include other partitions, should you make the system dual boot.

My personal experience is that it is **far faster**, and **far safer**, to rely on a disk image made with a reputable tool such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/). These are dedicated to making, to displaying, to restoring and to *verifying* images, since they show just what is being retained. It surprises that it is faster to restore the entire C:\ drive, when needed, than to use Windows Restore.

If you make images on a regular basis on separate media, e.g. a removable disk drive, you have backup even if your HDD or SSD dies. **Verify the image** to be sure you can see the files in it. Also **make bootable rescue media**, e.g. on a USB drive, which is easily done through most backup software.

Comment: Thanks for this, my friend recommended easeus, specifically this: https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/tb-free.html Would this do the job?

Comment: It should though I haven't used it myself. I've ha good experience using Reflect and DriveImage XML. BTW, make emergency *boot* media, e.g. a bootable USB drive, to allow loading the image from a *non-bootable* disk!